# Dropdown menu button doesn't close after click using angular5 and bootstrap4

Tags: javascript, html, angular, bootstrap-4

Here is the code

some.component.html

```
<div class="btn-group dropdown" normalizePosition ng-click="toggle()">
<button class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-sm btn-primary"
        data-toggle="dropdown"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="fa fa-cog"></i><span class="caret"></span> {{l("Edit")}}
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
        <a (click)="openReport(id)">{{l('Run Report')}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

some.component.ts

```
openReport(id): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/app/main/sale/viewer', id]);
}
```

When you are navigated to the sale viewer page in the browser the button is still showing and I'm not sure how to remove this after it's been clicked. Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: you are using angular 1 event binding syntax

Comment: Are you implying that I should be using another event binding syntax? @Chellappan

Comment: in angular 5 for event binding is different syntax (click)="toggle()"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51249090/angular-dropdown-directive-doesnt-work/51257095#51257095

Comment: still can't get it working

Comment: can you add your code in stackblitz.com